# Deploy smart contracts using web3j java library

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

I am using web3j java library to deploy a smart contract.

```
// I am encoding the constructor parameters here -- 2 & 3, 10 & 20
String encodedConstructor =
         FunctionEncoder.encodeConstructor(Arrays.asList(new Type(value), ...));

RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createContractTransaction(
    <nonce>,
    <gasPrice>,
    <gasLimit>,
    <value>,
    "0x <compiled smart contract code>" + encodedConstructor);

byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, <credentials>);

String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);
```

I am using

```
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(hexValue)
```

to deploy the contract.

My smart contract has a constructor which accepts some parameters(a, b) and it has a function **sum** which returns sum of a and b. After deployment if I call the **sum** function, it always returns me 0.

Need help.

Reference Link: https://docs.web3j.io/transactions.html#creation-of-a-smart-contract

Comment: but the contract is deployed well or not?

Comment: Contract got deployed. I got a pending transaction in txpool and after it was mined ,contract address was visible in the transaction receipt.

Comment: So the problem is the code of the smart contract not the deployment of the contract no? you have the code?

Comment: This is my contract bytecode, without encoded constructor parameters
6060604052341561000c57fe5b6040516040806100ea833981016040528080519060200190919080519060200190919050505b81600081905550806001819055505b50505b6098806100526000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff168063853255cc14603a575bfe5b3415604157fe5b6047605d565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60006001546000540190505b905600a165627a7a7230582045d4154b165a91bbd45e384793e99fa7799715f3adb510b137f7451a94623fd90029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to pass the required parameters in Web3J datatypes, [link on github](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/tree/master/abi/src/main/java/org/web3j/abi/datatypes).

A simple example is given in the a test file, [FunctionEncoderTest.java](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/36d5b6c79deec8786ce1724f623fc9f2639bdf96/abi/src/test/java/org/web3j/abi/FunctionEncoderTest.java).

```
 ArrayList<Type> dataParams = new ArrayList<>();    
 dataParams.add(new Utf8String("Name"));
 dataParams.add(new Address("Ethereum Address"));

 //This will be used for creating "RawTransaction" object
 Function function = new Function("updateDetails", dataParams, Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
```

Comment: How to get deployed contract address?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a Function Object for your smart contract constructor then in data field were you put compiled solidity add the decode result of this function 'compiled smart contract'+'decoded function of the constructor'